# Parse object of query string by using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to parse **filter** object of query string

```
localhost:3000/search/?filter={"data":true,"email":false}
```

Comment: you can't send object in the query string. stringify object and send in a query on server side parse it.

Comment: @RahulSharma you meant to say put stringify object in query string

Comment: yeah or `localhost:3000/search/?data=true&email=false` on server side you can create query like `var filter = {data: req.query.data,email:req.query.email}`

Comment: @RahulSharma url will work even if you send as an object, its by default considered as a string as per norms

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express then you can use following.

```
router.route('/search')
  .get((request, response) => {
    const filter = JSON.parse(request.query.filter)
    console.log(data.email); // false
    response.status(204).send();
  });
```

Or if you are using any other framework just use `JSON.parse(valid_json_string)`, that will convert your query string in json object